# Magento custom field in shipping method

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

How to add a field in shipping method dhl in admin area in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin config fields are added with system.xml field description. Look at this extension etc/system.xml and add your config field there

Comment: thanks! it works! Can you tell me how to display this field in front?

Comment: the answer is the same, look at this extension front-end files and see how they are acquired in there

Comment: Which extension??.. I dont see any extension here

Comment: extension where dhl admin structure is defined, it has a system.xml